# Slow performance of K Means clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, k-means

I have been using K-Means clustering in my project but it is taking a hell lot of time to get response, below is the code showing the usage will anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

```
for i in range(n_sentence):
    enc_email = enc_sentence[i]
    n_clusters = int(np.ceil(len(enc_email)**0.5))

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0)

    kmeans = kmeans.fit(enc_email)

    avg = []
    closest = []
    for j in range(n_clusters):
        idx = np.where(kmeans.labels_ == j)[0]
        avg.append(np.mean(idx))

    closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(kmeans.cluster_centers_,\
                                               enc_email)


    ordering = sorted(range(n_clusters), key=lambda k: avg[k])
    summary[i] = ' '.join([sentence[i][closest[idx]] for idx in ordering])

print('Clustering Finished')
```

Comment: Did you do any profiling? How do you know it's clustering that slows you down?

Comment: How big is your train data enc_email and if it is text then are you converting it to numerics?

Comment: The training data is variable but on an average we are getting 45k sentences each time.

Comment: could you be more precise than 'a hell lot of time' and what you would expect as not 'a hell lot of time'? . Could you please also provide the number of clusters and the size of the encoded (embedded i assume) sentence?

Comment: It is taking around 4-5 minutes for the clustering of around 2500 sentences on Amazon EC2 instance of 16GB RAM.